# PHP obsever pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am using a simple php observer pattern in zend. From controller notifing to the particular observer. In that input parameter is `id` and return type is `array`. Still is giving object as return response in controller. Subject as follow:

```
<?php

class Newsubject implements Subject{

    public $observers = array();

    function __construct() { }

    public function getdata(id){

        $this->id = id;

        $this->notify(id);
    }

    public function attach(Observer $obsever)
    {
        $id = spl_object_hash($obsever);
        $this->observers[$id] = $obsever;
    }

    public function detach(Observer $obsever)
    {
        $id = spl_object_hash($obsever);
        unset($this->observers[$id]);
    }

    public function notify(id)
    {
        foreach($this->observers as $obs)
        {
            $obs->update(id);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Observer as follow:

```
<?php

class Newobserver implements Observer{

    public function update($id)
    {
        $modelmethod = new Modelmethod();

        $modelmethod = $modelmethod->getdata($id);
        //which is an array
        return $modelmethod;
    }
}
?>
```

Call from controller:

```
$subject = new Newsubject();
$subject->attach(new Newobserver());
$id = 2;
$returnarray->getdata($id);

print_r($returnarray);
```

Output:

> Newsubject Object ( [observers] => Array ( [00000000243330360000000069e80d68] => Newobserver)

which it should return array.Any suggestion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets stack trace the flow -

```
$returnarray->getdata($id);
```

The above call `getdata($id)` calls `$this->notify(id);`.

`notify()` has the `observers[]` array but each key of this array has objects.

```
 foreach($this->observers as $obs)       /*$this->observers is array*/
 {
     $obs->update(id);        /*but $obs seems to be an object - individually*/
 }
```

Eg:
    `observers = array (
        Object (...),
        Object (...),
        Object (...),
    );`

Have a look into it.